# How To set Data In DataGridView by multiple selection of checkedListBox?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a iList in Which All Student Is there named as AllStudent 
i have 4 checkedListBox I want to filter grid data according to checkedlistbox checked items
[image: I want That Whwn]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
((DataTable)DataGridViews.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter =colmNameHere " like '%" + filterTextHere + "%'";
```

For this SO question `colmNameHere` like Class,Medium,Section and `filterTextHere` like Hostel,Primary,Hindi like wise.

Answer (score 1):

```
 try
            {

                List<lclsItemShdule> li = new List<lclsItemShdule>();
                List<lclsItemShdule> li2 = new List<lclsItemShdule>();
                foreach (clsMylist item in clbClass.CheckedItems)
                {
                    li.AddRange(ItemScheduleDetail.Where(w => w.ClassId ==   item.ItemData).ToList());
                }

                li2.AddRange(li);
                li.Clear();
                foreach (clsMylist item in clbMedium.CheckedItems)
                {
                    li.AddRange(li2.Where(w => w.MediumId == item.ItemData).ToList());
                }
                li2.Clear();
                li2.AddRange(li);
                li.Clear();
                foreach (clsMylist item in clbStream.CheckedItems)
                {
                    li.AddRange(li2.Where(w => w.StreamId == item.ItemData).ToList());
                }
                li2.Clear();
                li2.AddRange(li);
                li.Clear();
                foreach (clsMylist item in clbShift.CheckedItems)
                {
                    li.AddRange(li2.Where(w => w.ShiftId == item.ItemData).ToList());
                }
                li2.Clear();
                li2.AddRange(li);

                dgvItemSchedule.DataSource = null;
                dgvItemSchedule.DataSource = li2;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```